# Object or complement with "have"

Tags: grammar, objects, complements

Take the following sentence:

"He has blue eyes"

Does "blue eyes" act as an object or a complemet?

Would the answer be different in a sentence such as:

Comment: This question is probably more suited to [ell.se]. However, it appears to be incomplete.

Comment: But _blue eyes_ is the direct object of the verb _have_ in this sentence. Whether it is a "complement" or not depends on what **you** mean by "complement", and that's a matter between you and your confessor.

Comment: Have/has often has the meaning 'possess/ own etc.' and there it is a verb. He has.../He is having... He has had.... - all function like verbs. Others can throw more light.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little ambiguity in the way you phrased your question (since there are different types of complements), but I will assume you are asking if this is a subject complement.  A subject complement follows a linking verb; therefore, the verb "have" would not take a subject complement.  In your example, "He has blue eyes," "blue eyes" would act as an object of the verb "have."